# Python: Why does the variable appear to match the string, but the output says otherwise

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm making a simple script that checks to see if a user exit on a forum.

```
def xenforo_check():
    url = "http://dfkitcar.com/forum/index.php?login/login"
    name = "JSATX"
    headers = {'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8', 'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate', 'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    payload = {'login':name}

    response = requests.post(url, data=payload)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
    name_result = soup.find("div", class_="blockMessage blockMessage--error blockMessage--iconic").text

    if name_result == "Incorrect password. Please try again.":
        print("user found")
    elif name_result == "The requested user '"+name+"' could not be found.":
        print("user not found")
    else:
        print("possible error")

    print(name_result)

xenforo_check()
```

For this example the user does exist, so it should print "user found". Instead the output is:

```
possible error

Incorrect password. Please try again.
```

It seems to me that name_result is the same as "Incorrect password. Please try again." so I would expect it to print "user found".

The same thing has if I test a name that doesn't exit. The variable name_result doesn't equal the string. Why is this so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, `name_result` *seems* to be the same, but before testing it for comparison, `print` its contents and see what it *really* looks like:

```
>>> print(name_result)
u'\nIncorrect password. Please try again.\n'
```

So it's really a `unicode` string that contains non-visible characters, namely the newline character '`\n`', which is what it's really comparing against, and thus it doesn't match.

However, if we [`strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) these newline characters from the `text`, you should get your expected output, so add `strip()` to this line:

```
name_result = soup.find("div", class_="blockMessage blockMessage--error blockMessage--iconic").text.strip()
```